# Telling if a .Net app is running as service or app?

Tags: .net, testing, service, modal-dialog

How do you tell if a .Net application is running as a Desktop application or running as a service?

We are trying to test our application with Fitnesse, which loads the app up as a service then makes calls into it.. but when a modal error box is pushed then it blows up.. I want to put a check to see if it is running in a service and if it is I want to throw an exception instead so our test will fail.

Is there a way to do this, other than passing a parameter to somewhere saying it was started by FitNesse?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to determine whether or not to show a UI control, you can use:

```
if( Environment.UserInteractive )
{
    // Show UI
}
```

Comment: +1 for a simpler solution than inspecting the assembly's type.

Comment: Not sure what the difference is, but Form.ShowDialog uses SystemInformation.UserInteractive to perform the same check.

Comment: Judging by the Reflector output, two different people wrote Environment.UserInteractive and SystemInformation.UserInteractive using the same underlying API (GetUserObjectInformation) but without looking at the other's code.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* this will work (no convenient place to test my air code):

```
// requires a 'using System.ServiceProcess' statement
type = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().EntryPoint.DeclaringType;
bool isRunningAsAService = type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(ServiceBase));
```